# Radiation heat exchange between grey bodies formula explanation

Tags: thermodynamics, radiation

Given two grey bodies (heat emissivity = heat absorbtion, emissivity($\lambda$) = constant = $\epsilon$ foreach $\lambda$) in a vacuum, how much power P would the hotter transmit to the coldest?

S1, S2 are the surfaces of the bodies "that face each other"

T1, T2 are the temperatures of the bodies

heat emissivity = heat absorbtion, emissivity($\lambda$) = constant = $\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2$ foreach $\lambda$

R is the distance between them

$\sigma$ Constant of Stefan Boltzman

$\theta_1, \theta_2$ are the angles of the normal of each surface of each body with the line the joins them.

[image: Image of the book]

$$F = \int_{S_1} \int_{S_2} \frac{cos(\theta_1)cos(\theta_2)dS_1dS_2}{\pi*R^2} $$

$$P = \frac{\sigma(T_1^4 - T_2^4)}{\frac{1-\epsilon_1}{\epsilon_1*S_1} + \frac{1-\epsilon_2}{\epsilon_2*S_2} + \frac{1}{F}}$$

This is taken from page 506 of "Mencuccini Silvestrini Fisica Meccanica e Termodinamica" (translated by me)

The book lacks much (if any) explanation of neither the formula nor the integral, I am interested in both intuition for this formula and proofs of it.

Comment: A diagram of the physical setup would certainly help.

Comment: @DavidWhite added the image from the book

Comment: $F$ is called the view factor and has to do with how well the two bodies can see (and thus exchange radiation with) each other. Two plates facing each other would have a high $F$, while two plates lying in the same plane would have a low $F$.